# VBA - Allocation of Information based on another cell's value

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I have a list of assets I wish to allocate to resources based on whether or not they are available.

Both lists are variable in length.

I am chasing a macro which will look down list 1 and if there is a resource available then it will look over to list 2 and take the next asset.

Answer (score 0):

Try Range.Find Method

[Range.Find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)

Comment: Thanks - will have a look.  I am quite ok with formulas in excel but not so good with vba. if I was to use the find i assume i would define the first list as my range, find the 'tigger values' and then write into the adjacent column using an offset function and a copy and paste from my second list?  sound about right?

Comment: You got it! :) Since you mentioned copy and paste, let me give you a tip. **Line1: Range("A1").Copy    Line2: Range("B1").Paste** can be also written as **Line1: Range("A1").Copy Range("B1")** and this also can be **Range("B1") = Range("A1").Value** Only difference between using *Copy* and *=* is that with *Copy*, Range("B1") will become exactly same as Range("A1"). (Formula, Formatting.....just like Copy). **=** will only get value (If A1 is formula, B1 will not get it's formula but the value).If you want the formula, You can apply **Range("A1").Formula**